Turning thumbs, waiting for a review audit test
As described in this other question, sometimes the creation of an audit test takes several seconds, making it a real giveaway.
Is there a way to improve the performance?

You can have a look at Do audit revision take longer to load than actual revisions? and Review - audit questions take longer to load?

@Glorfindel: if this situation already exists for eleven years, I don't think a solution can be expected soon? :-)

I guess it's sort of [tag:status-bydesign], yes.

status-by-tradition
